# C# Winforms ListView DoubleClick event anywhere

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm trying to get the following functionality in my winform:

I need so that every time a someone double clicks inside my ListView, something will happen, but the event seems to only trigger when double clicking on a row containing an item in the ListView instead of anywhere in the ListView (including the empty area below all the items).

What event will fire when double clicking *anywhere* in the ListView?

Thanks

Comment: Use the MouseDoubleClick event.  If you want to find out if anything interesting was clicked then use the HitTest() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably achieve the required behavior by inheriting from ListView, and overriding the method OnNotifyMessage().

In that method, you'll have to intercept the correct message: WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK (or similar).

That's not going to be the prettiest code you've ever written, but should get you the results.

Answer (score 2):

you can used the ListView1_MouseDown event rather than click

Comment: I should have been more clear in the question (as I was in the title) - I am only interested in double clicking (although your solution does work).

Comment: In MouseDown event handler, write your code as follows:
if (e.Clicks == 2)
{
   /* your code responding to a double-click */
}